# How can I move a system app from one phone to another?

Tags: samsung

I like the music player on my older samsung phone and want to have it on my new phone. The music player is a system app and I can't simply install it in .apk form normally. Is there a way I can move it to my new phone?

Comment: Not unless you have root privileges in order to pull the APK from the old phone and push it in the new one. Even if you did, the app might not work if the two OSes are too much different.

Answer (score 0):

There are many apps which can take backup of system app like [AndroZip](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.agilesoftresource&hl=en) (it can save .apk file of system app in sd card) then you can transfer it to your new phone via bluetooth etc.

[Steps To Backup App Using AndroZip.](http://www.aryktech.com/2013/08/android-users-how-to-back-up-your_18.html)

- Open AndroZip
- Go To **App** tab.
- Check Music Player you want to get apk.
- Click Backup.

apk file will be in app_backup folder in sdcard.